# paper accepted by still not published online for more than 7 months

Tags: publications

I have paper got accepted, and it said the proof will be sent in 30 business days, now I already waited for 7 months, with around 9 emails asking what happen, but no one responded. In this case, what can be done? Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are there **any** papers published online recently for that journal?  If so, do they say when they were accepted?

Comment: yes, I saw papers published that were accepted around February 2024. This makes me feel not just being slow, but some issues here.

Comment: Did you submit the paper yourself? If not check that an embargo was not placed on it by whomever submitted it because I have had that experience too

Comment: yes I submitted myself. Not get what you mean, do you mind sharing more details?

Answer (score 3):

The best response for your situation depends on your field and the specific journal you're publishing in, but I can give you a few items to check that are fairly universal.

- Are you emailing the correct people? Post-acceptance, your paper is likely handled by the journal staff, not the editor who accepted your paper.
- Have you checked your spam folder? It's not unheard of for emails from reputable journals to get flagged by a spam filter.
- Did you send the journal everything they may have asked for after acceptance? For example, high quality files for any figures? Or a publication fee, if applicable?

If you're sure those points aren't your issue, and you don't hear back from the journal soon, withdrawing and submitting your paper elsewhere may be your last resort.

Comment: Thanks. After acceptance, they just say they will save a proof and without asking me anything.